# Sql query to retrieve rows that have only 'emp' and not anything else

Tags: sql, oracle

This is how my table looks:

| col1 | col2 |
| --- | --- |
| Date 1 | 'EMP' |
| Date 1 | 'FSA' |
| Date 1 | 'ONL' |
| DATE 2 | 'EMP' |
| Date 3 | 'FSA' |

I want to retrieve rows that have only 'EMP' and not anything else. In this case, I should be getting only Date 2 as output and not Date 1.

Can anyone help me with the query?

Comment: [It appears no attempt was made](https://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/)

Comment: **Try writing something yourself** and then if it doesn't work, show us specifically what you did so we can help you along. You start it, and then we help. We don't write it for you. Show us the actual code that you've tried, and then describe what happened and what's not right, and then we can help you from there. Chances are you'll get pretty close to the answer if you just try it yourself first.

Comment: Why only the row with Date2?  You have _two_ rows with the required 'EMP'.

Answer (score 1):

You can use subquery as below:

```
select * from table where col1 not in (select col1 from table where col2 != 'EMP');
```

Answer (score 0):

here is one way:

```
select * from tablename t1
where col2 = 'emp'
and not exists (select 1 from tablename t2 where t1.date = t2.date and t2.col2 <> 'emp')
```

or you can use window functions:

```
select * from (
  select *, count(case when col2 <> 'EMP' then 1 end) over (partition by col1) cnt
  from tablename
) t
where t.cnt = 0 
and t.col2 = 'emp'
```

Comment: the first query is giving me 'missing left paranthesis error'. Is it in oracle

Comment: I missed table alias for col2 inside subquery , "t2.col2" , try now

Comment: select * from table CSESDEV02.BATCH_CONTROL_INFO ACTIONBATCHCONTROLINFORMATION
where ACTIONBATCHCONTROLINFORMATION.CDE_BTCH_SRCE = 'EMP'
and not exists (select 1 from table CSESDEV02.BATCH_CONTROL_INFO ACTIONBATCHCONTROLINFORMATION2 where ACTIONBATCHCONTROLINFORMATION.DTE_CRTE_BC = ACTIONBATCHCONTROLINFORMATION2.DTE_CRTE_BC and ACTIONBATCHCONTROLINFORMATION2.CDE_BTCH_SRCE <> 'EMP')    -I added alias before itself. this is the actual query. it results in that left paranthesis error

Comment: @ushaduddu oh ,remove "table" keyword before tablenames : `select
    *
from
     CSESDEV02.BATCH_CONTROL_INFO ACTIONBATCHCONTROLINFORMATION
where
    ACTIONBATCHCONTROLINFORMATION.CDE_BTCH_SRCE = 'EMP'
    and not exists (
        select
            1
        from
            CSESDEV02.BATCH_CONTROL_INFO ACTIONBATCHCONTROLINFORMATION2
        where
            ACTIONBATCHCONTROLINFORMATION.DTE_CRTE_BC = ACTIONBATCHCONTROLINFORMATION2.DTE_CRTE_BC
            and ACTIONBATCHCONTROLINFORMATION2.CDE_BTCH_SRCE <> 'EMP'
    )`

Answer (score 0):

Here goes your query. You added `table` key word before table names. That's the problem.

```
select * from CSESDEV02.BATCH_CONTROL_INFO ACTIONBATCHCONTROLINFORMATION 
where ACTIONBATCHCONTROLINFORMATION.CDE_BTCH_SRCE = 'EMP' 
and not exists (select 1 from CSESDEV02.BATCH_CONTROL_INFO ACTIONBATCHCONTROLINFORMATION2 where ACTIONBATCHCONTROLINFORMATION.DTE_CRTE_BC = ACTIONBATCHCONTROLINFORMATION2.DTE_CRTE_BC and ACTIONBATCHCONTROLINFORMATION2.CDE_BTCH_SRCE <> 'EMP')
```